# Getting authorizations info interable in telethon?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I'm using telethon with python 3.x. What I'm trying to get is the last active day of all my authorizations in my telegram account. For that I have this code.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions
api_id = XXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXX'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

result = client(functions.account.GetAuthorizationsRequest())

auths_list = result.__getattribute__('authorizations')

str = ''.join(str(e) for e in auths_list)
print(str)
```

result:

```
Authorization(hash=0, device_model='Windows', platform='Android', system_version='10', api_id=123321123213124, app_name='Telethon32113223', app_version='1.6.21', date_created=1323211, date_active=15553213125321213312312312, ip='8.2.3.21', country='pava, German', region='', current=True, official_app=False, password_pending=False)Authorization(hash=94219421213090, device_model='Xiaomi', platform='Android', system_version='9 P (28)', api_id=21213, app_name='Telegram Android', app_version='5.5.0', date_created=19123913299, date_active=12133213, ip='98.2.2.2.2', country='pava, Spain', region='', current=False, official_app=True, password_pending=False)Authorization(hash=9321123321231123321, device_model='PC', platform='', system_version='Windows 10', api_id=3211323213212, app_name='Telegram Desktop', app_version='1.6.7', date_created=1213321321312213, date_active=11233213213218, ip='1.2.2.25', country='pava, Spain', region='', current=False, official_app=True, password_pending=False)Authorization(hash=4124214212511832189321, device_model='PC', platform='', system_version='Windows 10', api_id=213231321321, app_name='Telegram Desktop', app_version='1.6.7', date_created=12133213211322, date_active=3213213213219, ip='2.2.2.5', country='pava, Spain', region='', current=False, official_app=True, password_pending=False)
```

I get all the info I need but I just need all the authorizations' date_active=XXXXXX.
When print `str` I get the whole response.

Comment: If it is an Authorization object, can you access any variables? If it is just a string you have you tried with a simple regex?

Comment: Im not experienced with regular expresions. i conver it to str . How i can acces the variables, it returns 4 authorization objetcs each one for each authorization

Comment: Have you looked at the possibility of `to_dict()` to turn this object in a dictionary? you could then use `dict_name['date_active']`.